# How to increase data buffer size ceiling of RIA Services queries?

Tags: silverlight, service, ria

To any RIA Services gurus out there, anyone know how to increase the data buffer size ceiling of RIA Services query data coming back to the Silverlight client?

I have a RIA Services query where it is returning a parent entity along with quite a few child entity collections coming back as part of the data response. The code for my RIA Services query begins like this:

```
   1:  [EnableClientAccess()]
   2:  public class ContactsDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService
   3:  {
   4:       [Query(ResultLimit = 150)]
   5:       public IQueryable SearchContacts(string jobFunction = default(string),
   6:                                                    string workPhone = default(string),
   7:                                                    string officeLocation = default(string),
   8:                                                    string firstName = default(string),
   9:                                                    string lastName = default(string),
  10:                                                    string address1 = default(string),
  11:                                                    string address2 = default(string),
  12:                                                    string city = default(string),
  13:                                                    int stateTypeId = 0,
  14:                                                    string zip = default(string),
  15:                                                    string email = default(string),
  16:                                                    Nullable departmentTypeId = null,
  17:                                                    Nullable sectionTypeId = null,
  18:                                                    Nullable divisionTypeId = null,
  19:                                                    Nullable governmentTypeId = null)
  20:       {
  21:            var results = from r in this.ObjectContext.Contacts
  22:                                       .Include("ContactAddresses")
  23:                                       .Include("ContactAddresses.CityType")
  24:                                       .Include("ContactAddresses.StateType")
  25:                                       .Include("ContactDepartments")
  26:                                       .Include("ContactDepartments.DepartmentType")
  27:                                       .Include("ContactDivisions")
  28:                                       .Include("ContactDivisions.DivisionType")
  29:                                       .Include("ContactEmails")
  30:                                       .Include("ContactGovernments")
  31:                                       .Include("ContactGovernments.GovernmentType")
  32:                                       .Include("ContactJobFunctions")
  33:                                       .Include("ContactJobFunctions.JobFunctionType")
  34:                                       .Include("ContactOffices")
  35:                                       .Include("ContactPhones")
  36:                                       .Include("ContactPhones.PhoneType")
  37:                                       .Include("ContactSections")
  38:                                       .Include("ContactSections.SectionType")
  39:                          select r;
```

I have confirmed thru testing that the  [Query(ResultLimit = 150)] decorator will cause the overall RIA Services query, SearchContacts(), to fail and throw and exception if you increase 150 to 500. I am guessing I'm hitting an overall data limitation of RIA Services.

I googled a bit for this issue and it looks like you can increase the data buffer size of a WCF Web Service (note WCF Service, not RIA Service), by editing the web config settings, but not sure if this would also work in a RIA Services query.

If anyone has come across the same issue and found a resolution, please respond.

thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this thread

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/150041/337439.aspx

Comment: Gene, thanks for the link...that did the trick! Seems a little strange that Microsoft doesn't exactly advertise how to accomplish this...would have been nice for them to at least add in a web.config comment with an example showing how to increase the buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming an error is being raised from the server?

Or are you running into an overhead on the client? I have run into no discernable buffer size limitation on the client (although I'm sure they are there).

You do need to raise the buffer size for WCF services when transporting a lot of data. I don't have a specific reference available right now but do a search on web.config WCF buffer size and you should come up with some hits.

It is good that it generates this way since you probably don't want to open up a bandwidth issue due to data retreival on generation. Although I do remember having a hard time finding the information when I first encoutered this.